# ¿Cuál es el origen de "lea"?

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos

El sustantivo femenino **LEA** aparece definido en varios diccionarios (1853 Dominguez suplemento, 1855 Gaspar y Roig, 1869 Domíguez suplemento; RAE Manual 1927, 1950, 1984, 1989) como **ramera** (en los primeros como *vulg* o *germ*, en los de la RAE, como *fam*. y en las dos últimas ediciones, como apunta @Charlie, como *desus*).

En los demás diccionarios que he podido consultar mediante el NTLLE no figura (por ejemplo, en ninguna de las restantes ediciones del DLE entre 1927 y 1989), al igual que tampoco figura en la edición actual del DLE.

En el "**Diccionario de argot español**" de Luis Besses (1905 según [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_Besses) se recoge:

> **Lea**
>   d. Prostituta. || Peseta.   [la *d.* indica *argot delincuente*]

En el **Diccionario Etimológico** de Corominas tampoco aparece.

En el **Diccionario de María Moliner** aparece como **f. *Prostituta*** sin ninguna otra marca; en el **Diccionario del Español Actual** de Manuel Seco aparece con la marca (*jerg.*).

¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra? ¿Tal vez hay una relación con el episodio bíblico del [primer matrimonio de Jacob](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lea)? y ¿por qué ha tenido esa extraña vida en el DLE, apareciendo solo en algunas ediciones, desapareciendo después?

Comment: Buscando en la sección "Libros" del buscador Google veo que la palabra aparece en varias recopilaciones de vocabulario **gitano** (principalmente Francisco de Sales Mayo, aprox. 1870). También se menciona como voz **catalana** y también de **Navarra**. Y en un libro de 2007 se dice que _lea_ es prostituta por analogía con la _leona_, supongo que por ser "fiera" o "apasionada". De todo esto no tengo más antecedentes, así que no te puedo ayudar con una buena respuesta.

Answer (score 6):

Debe de ser una palabra de uso en ámbitos restringidos, ya sea de forma geográfica, temporal, social o lo que sea. En todas las ediciones del *Academia manual* aparece la definición precedida por un corchete, lo que significa que es una entrada, digamos, en grado de tentativa. Como dice la propia RAE, las voces precedidas de corchetes en el *Academia manual* son vocablos "que la Academia no censura, pero que aún no se decide a incorporar a su léxico". Y de hecho en las ediciones de 1984 y 1989 ya aparece como "en desuso", por lo que nunca llegó a tener la ocasión de incorporarse a dicho léxico "oficial".

Complicado resulta buscar en el CORDE alguna acepción de *lea* con el significado de "ramera", dado que los casos que veo son todos del subjuntivo de *leer*. Paso a buscar en el *Fichero general* pues. Aquí sí veo varias fichas que recogen el significado de *lea* que nos atañe. Se ve que es una voz de la germanía, que no se debió de popularizar como muchas otras. Una ficha la sitúa en Pamplona y la asemeja a las voces *pilurri* y *leona*. Otra ficha de 1980 afirma que es una voz marginal. Otra curiosamente suaviza su significado a "amiga preferida" o "novia". Otra ficha afirma:

> Su significación se ha ido desplazando. Hace algunos años, esta palabra fue sinónimo de 'mujer' y más tarde de 'prostituta'. Llegó a nosotros a través de la germanía *lumia* 'ramera'.

Fíjate que *[lumia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NhbNLCL)* sí aparece en el DLE (y como sinónimo de *prostituta*, aunque poco usada). Esta ficha (y alguna otra que he visto) hablan sobre el español de Cuba, así que me voy al CORDE y restrinjo la búsqueda a este país:

> *[...] encontramos en Las Vegas a Arsenio Cué, que nos estuvo evitando no invitando toda la noche porque estaba con una hembra vulgo lea, geva o ninpha [...].*
>
> Guillermo Cabrera Infante, "Tres tristes tigres", 1964-1967 (Cuba).

Dado esto pensé que la palabra tal vez aparecería en el *Diccionario de americanismos*, pero no es así. El caso es ese, que ha sido una palabra de muy poco uso (y ese poco uso puede ser temporal, porque en otra ficha de 1921 dice que fue común tanto en España como en gran parte de América) y por tanto no ha llegado a pasar en diccionarios de ese "grado de tentativa" mencionado. Debió tener un auge a principios del siglo XX y por eso se planteó su inclusión en el diccionario, pero acabó cayendo rápidamente en desuso.

Answer (score 3):

El suplemento del diccionario de Dominguez (1853), consultable mediante el [NTLLE](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) recoge para "LEA", entre otras, la siguiente definición:

> Geog. ant. Nombre de una isla de Venus, situada cerca de Cineráica.

Dada la relación de Venus con el sexo (véase, por ejemplo, la acepción 4ª de **venus** en el actual [Diccionario de la lengua española](https://dle.rae.es/venus?):

> 4. f. desus. Deleite sexual o acto carnal.

quizás sea esta hipotética relación el origen de la acepción de lea = ramera.